# How can I calculate GPS satellite's Latitude and Longitude if I have the elevation and the azimuth

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, orbit, gps

Please tell me how I can calculate a GPS satellite's latitude and longitude if I have the elevation and the azimuth angles.

I am using a septentrio GPS receiver.

Thanks

Comment: GPS satellites constantly broadcast their ephemeris.  Might it be better to use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the latitude and longitude of a GPS satellite using its elevation and azimuth, you will need to use a mathematical formula known as the **"Haversine Formula"**. This formula takes into account the curvature of the Earth and provides an accurate solution for calculating the distance between two points on the Earth's surface.

To use the Haversine Formula, you will need to know the following information:

• The latitude and longitude of the observer (your current location)
• The elevation and azimuth of the satellite (in degrees)
• The radius of the Earth (in kilometers)

Once you have all of this information, you can calculate the latitude and longitude of the satellite using the following formula:

Latitude = arcsin(sin(observerLatitude) * cos(azimuth) + cos(observerLatitude) * sin(azimuth) * cos(elevation))

Longitude = observerLongitude + arctan2(sin(azimuth) * sin(elevation), cos(observerLatitude) * cos(elevation) - sin(observerLatitude) * sin(elevation) * cos(azimuth))

Using this formula, you can calculate the latitude and longitude of any GPS satellite given its elevation and azimuth.

Comment: Thank you very much. please do you have a reference to your answer?